# Python: Problem when making a dict from a text file

Tags: python

My text file looks like this:

```
comp_1-item_14, 
comp_2-item_1,item_7,item_35
comp_3-item_4,item_7,item_10,item_1,item_2
```

I want to make a dictionary from the text file. It should look like

```
{"comp_1": ("item_14"), "comp_2": ("item_1","item_7","item_35")}
```

How can i delete the '-' from this and fix it? My code is so:

```
d = {}
with open('pr.txt', 'r') as p:
    for line in r:
        split = line.split()
        d[split[0]] = "-".join(split[0:])
        print(d)
```

Comment: you didn't given any input in `split()` method. and don't save it as `split`. `s = line.strip().split('-')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried with a single line and it works fine :

```
line = "comp_3-item_4,item_7,item_10,item_1,item_2"

d = {}
line_list  = line.split('-')
d[line_list[0]] = tuple(line_list[1].split(','))
print(d)
```

Output :

```
{'comp_3': ('item_4', 'item_7', 'item_10', 'item_1', 'item_2')}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `split = line.split()` to `split = line.split('-')`

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
d = {}
with open('pr.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        split_ = l.strip().split("-")
        d[split_[0]] = tuple(x for x in split_[1].split(",") if x)
```

---

```
{'comp_1': ('item_14',), 'comp_2': ('item_1', 'item_7', 'item_35')...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
with open('pr.txt', 'r') as p:
    for line in p:
        s = line.strip().split('-')
        d[s[0]] = "".join(s[1:])
print(d)
```